# Checking the DateTime in the dd-MMM-yy

Tags: c#, string, datetime

The input parameter to the Web API is the DateTime datatype.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails(string ROOM, DateTime DOB_GT)
```

I need to check if the entered DOB_GT is of the format of dd-MMM-yy else I will have to return a JSON response of "error":"Invalid Date Format". Most of the examples are dealing with `DateTime.TryParseExact` and it requires string. Should I convert the DateTime to string first and then use `DateTime.TryParseExact` or are there any other way of doing this

Comment: It's already a DateTime, it's not in any particular format. If you need to parse something, it's not in this function.

Comment: A datetime variable has no format. At this point it is too late to check in which format your user typed the date

Comment: Should I receive them in String so I can check?

Comment: @Steve can you please help me how would I be checking if the DataeTime we received is valid

Comment: If your backend expects a DateTime variable there is no way to check the format of the original string as your user typed it. Once that string has been converted in a DateTime then it is stored inside the variable as a series of digits and looses any kind of 'formatting'. This validation could be done by your backend only if you pass the same string typed by the user otherwise the validation should occur client side.  Of course your backend could check if the date is inside allowed limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steve and Francis point out, since the `DOB_GT` variable is already a `DateTime` object you can assume the value of it is a VALID date because invalid DateTime objects will crash when created/instantiated and therefore you would not be able to pass it to your method. Since it is a valid date you can specify the format you want when you need to use it. To format the DateTime object as you specify try the String.Format option. Example to format as dd-MMM-yy...

```
Console.WriteLine(DOB_GT.ToString(String.Format("dd-MMM-yy")));
```

This will output something like... 17-Nov-16.

Hope this helps.

Comment: error CS1501: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments